# Is it possible to run RepastJ model in a web browser

Tags: agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

I am new to agent based modeling, and am running the demo model that come along with the RepastJ (Repast 3). Is it possible to run the simulation in a web browser? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this,will help you a lot :)

If you are using a PC:

Go to the Java website to obtain a free copy of the Java software, and download Java (at least the
Java Runtime Environment), if it is not already on the PC to be used.
Then download RepastJ to run the Basic Immune Simulator.

If you are using a Mac:

A copy of JAVA is NOT needed. Simply, download the OS X version of Repast J.
Install the Repast J that is appropriate for your operating system by following the instructions
provided on the Repast website for the downloads. Be sure to download the correct version of
Repast J for your computer.
Download the Basic Immune Simulator file (BasicImmuneSimulator.jar) onto your computer.
Once the above steps have been completed, the simulation may be run as follows:

- Start Repast either by clicking on the icon or by finding the repastj.exe file within the repast
  directory and clicking on it. The Repast toolbar should appear.
- At the left edge of the toolbar there is an icon of a folder.
- Click on the folder and a “Load Model” pane appears.
- Scroll down in the Load Model pane and click on “Models” and then the “Add” button.
- A browser will appear. Use this browser to find the BasicImmuneSimulator.jar file, which can be
  found where ever it was downloaded.
- Click on the BasicImmuneSimulator.jar file and "Basic Immune Model" will appear under “Other
  Models”.
- Click on the “Load” button, to make the Basic Immune Model graphical user interface (GUI)
  appear.
- Once "Basic Immune Model Settings" GUI appears, click on the "Parameters" tab to see the input
  parameter choices available for a simulation run, if the parameters are not already displayed.
- Choose the pathological challenge from the list in the GUI. Any other parameter may be
  changed to the user’s discretion at this point as well.
- Click the Run button (triangle) on the Repast toolbar to start the simulation.
  Note that data files from the simulation will be saved automatically to wherever the repastj.exe file
  is located.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to trigger the simulation from a web browser?